# Laplace equation in a circle with non-continuous Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I have to solve:

> $$ \begin{cases}
> u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta}=0 & [0,1) \times [-\pi,\pi] \\ 
> u(1,\theta)=0 & (-\pi,0) & (1) \\
> u(1,\theta)=1 & (0,\pi) & (2) \\
> \end{cases} $$

And **show that $u$ and $u_{\theta}$ are continuous in $[0, \frac{1}{2}] \times [-\pi,\pi]$**. So, as u cannot be continuous in $[-\pi,\pi] \times [0,1]$ due to the discontinuity:

Given the solutions in separated variables $1,r^k(a_k\cos(k\theta)+b_k\sin(k\theta))$, I have tried to define the solution so that it is continuous inside the circle.

Usually I would compute the Fourier coefficients for 1 and 0. But this produces a discontinuity at $\theta=0$ as it gives me:

$$u(r,\theta)=0, \theta \in (-\pi,0]$$
$$ u(r, \theta)=1, \theta \in (0, \pi] $$

**But** In this case, as I am asked to show that **$u$ and $u_{\theta}$ are continuous in   $[0, \frac{1}{2}] \times [-\pi,\pi]$**, I don't know how to proceed.

Maybe I could define it as $u(r,\theta)=1$ everywhere inside the circle and then as the Boundary conditions define?

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed as usual. The Fourier coefficients of a piecewise defined functions are still computed as an integral: 
$$
a_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u(1,\theta) \cos k\theta\,d\theta
$$
It's just that to evaluate this, you'll have to split the integral into the *sum* of two:
$$
a_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0} u(1,\theta) \cos k\theta\,d\theta + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} u(1,\theta) \cos k\theta\,d\theta =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} 1 \cos k\theta\,d\theta
$$
Notice how the *cases* translate into summation in the formula for coefficients. The coefficients themselves are not case-defined; indeed they are just numbers, independent of $\theta$. So, when you form the Fourier series with these coefficients, you have continuous terms.

*Fourier series are never case-defined, even if the function is.*

To prove continuity, you need uniform convergence on the specified set. The Weierstrass M-test will do the job: the supremum of the $k$th term is at most some constant times $(1/2)^k$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have computed the coefficients and I got $-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{r^{2n+1}}{ \pi (2n+1)} \sin((2n+1) \theta)$ .

Comment: Now using Wierstrass M-test I can use $|f_n| \leq \frac{2 r^{2n+1}}{\pi}$, which is a geometric series and converges as $r \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Is this correct for proving the continuity of u? To prove the continuity of $u_{\theta} $ I can do the same derivating every term.

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. Except you should have a constant term $1/2$ in the expansion.

Comment: Instead of the -2 ?

Comment: I mean a constant term, $\frac12 + $ other stuff you have

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot to put it here.